# How to type with typescript a angularfire observable?

Tags: typescript, angularfire2

I am trying to use angularfire properly and type it. But I always have this error :

```
 getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.db.collection('chat').valueChanges();
```

}[image]

I tried this workaround, but is not clean

```
 getMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return <any>this.db.collection('chat').valueChanges();
```

Comment: See if any of the methods in `this.db.collection('chat').valueChanges()` are generic. My bet is that `collection` is generic and `this.db.collection<ChatMessage>('chat').valueChanges()` should work.

Comment: Yes! Do you have any link to documentation about this ?

Comment: It was just a guess, based on how such APIs usually work :). The idea is that there is not enough info there to get to the `ChatMessage` type so you probably have to specify it somewhere, and `collection` seemed like a logical answer. Anyway, someone seems to have posted an answer with a link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
this.db.collection<ChatMessage>('chat')
```

As you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RTDB:

```js
this.db.list<ChatMessage>('chat');
```

as you can see here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Comment: Giving more details and explanation is always better.